# Executing SQL query with params at SQLite and Xamarin iOS app

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, xamarin

I'm following [this guide](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/) to do a custom query with params using SQLite at Xamarin iOS app:

```
select * from [Contact] where FirstName = 'Alex'
```

When I query it using plain string it works fine:

```
_db.Query<Contact>("select * from [Contact] where FirstName = 'Alex'").ToList();
```

but I want to execute it using params to avoid injections:

```
_db.Query<Contact>("select * from [Contact] where FirstName = '?'", "Alex").ToList();
```

> Trace:  Executing Query: select * from [Contact] where FirstName = '?'
>   0: First1

Unfortunately it returns 0 results (while initial query returns the required data).

Answer (score 0):

Turned out all you need is to use Trace=true to see how it is done by the framework itself.

Querying by =

```
Executing Query: select * from "Contact" where ("FirstName" = ?)
  0: Alex
```

Using like:

```
Executing Query: select * from "Contact" where ("FirstName" like ('%' || ? || '%'))
  0: Alex
```